# Combine tables in excel using powerquery

Tags: excel, datatable, powerquery

I have 10 excel files containing product data from suppliers, and often I would have to load these in individually, therefor I am looking for a way to combine all these tables into one big table and import it like that.

I have tried to use excel's powerquery to achieve this, but there's an issue: from my understanding you need to supply a sample file and the query will use this file as a base to merge the other data from other files into. The reason this is problematic is because I need to also include unique columns from files that don't appear in the sample persé.

I have looked up videos endlessly on how to achieve a result that will merge all the files, combine on column name if possible, and simply include all the unique columns from other files as well, into a table.

Is such feature available for powerquery? Or should I be starting to look into different ways to achieve this?

I'm afraid I'm unable to share the files since they contain data, but they're technically just a bunch of tables in excel

Comment: There's no need to share the actual data -- it would preferable to make up a representative data set that mimics the problem, so others can reproduce your problem and help you devise a solution

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps at all with the very little information you have provided.

It combines all sheets from all workbooks in a specified directory using powerquery.  You can edit the path and file extension, then paste it into data ... get data .. from other sources ... blank query ... home ... advanced editor...

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```